# Como tratar erros em caso de falha no simplexml_load_file em PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Tenho uma rotina para acessar o webservice dos correios que usa simplexml_load_file, porém se por algum motivo o site dos correios estiverem fora do ar ou si demorar muito para responder meu site retorna um erro, então gostaria de tratar este erro do carregamento do simplexml_load_file, para que eu possa apresentar uma mensagem personalizada ao usuário, tentei de algumas formas mais sem sucesso, segue meu código atual:

```
    $url = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?";
    $url .= "nCdEmpresa=" . $cod_administrativo;
    $url .= "&sDsSenha=" . $senha;
    $url .= "&sCepOrigem=" . $cep_origem;
    $url .= "&sCepDestino=" . $cep_destino;
    $url .= "&nVlPeso=" . $peso;
    $url .= "&nVlLargura=" . $largura;
    $url .= "&nVlAltura=" . $altura;
    $url .= "&nCdFormato=1";
    $url .= "&nVlComprimento=" . $comprimento;
    $url .= "&sCdMaoPropria=" . $mao_propria;
    $url .= "&nVlValorDeclarado=" . $valor;
    $url .= "&sCdAvisoRecebimento=" . $aviso_recebimento;
    $url .= "&nCdServico=" . $servico;
    $url .= "&nVlDiametro=0";
    $url .= "&StrRetorno=xml";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);    

    if ($xml === false || $xml === 0 || $xml === "") {

        return '';
    }

    return $xml->cServico;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece ser um caso para utilizar o `try{}... catch(){}`.

**Link da documentação:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

```
try {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url)
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "Código que será executado após o try catch.";
}
```

Uma observação importante sobre o trecho de código acima é que o finally sempre será executado após um try catch. Se não desejar esse comportamento, basta remover o bloco `finally`

Update: Esse trecho de código parece funcionar corretamente apenas na versão do PHP7 ou posterior.

Answer (score 0):

Isso aqui deve funcionar, mas se você quiser algo mais robusto sugiro utilizar uma componente de terceiro que carregue xml.

```
// nescessário pra consegui pegar os errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
if ($xml === false) {
    $message = '';
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        $message .= $error->message;
    }
    throw new Exception(trim($message));
}
```

Obs: Aqui ele ta jogando uma exception quando tem erro mas caso não seja nescessário  é só adptar pra suas necessidades.

Comment: Nada ainda, fiz conforme vc disse e o erro ainda continua